# ElementaryOS Juno - random system freezes

Tags: release-juno

My elementary OS on laptop Lenovo Legion Y530 sometimes freezes when I try to watch video oraz browse facebook or something more heavier work for processor. Before system freezing in logs I get this:

```
mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU9: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU11: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU10: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU8: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)

mce: CPU8: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
```

After this I need to reboot system with the power button.

Can any one help me with this? This problem is very bothersome.

Best regards
Łukasz

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities, most likely not Elementary related.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/941686/cpu-hardware-errors-in-ubuntu-17-04

- update your bios
- Clean fans
- You can throttle your cpu, but that is only a temporal solution

Comment: I already did every point from this link and still system freeze. Bios is in actual version and fans are cleared.